# Adding ticks between months on x-axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm trying to add ticks *between* the months on the x-axis using ggplot2 - something like this:

[image]

instead of the standard ticks *at* the months.

My process thus far has been as follows (for example):

```
y=(1:1:12)
x=seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="months")
df=data.frame(x,y)
g<-ggplot(df,aes(x,y))
g<-g+geom_line()
g<-g+scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"),breaks = date_breaks("months"))
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I'd like those x-axis ticks to be between the months. I've tried using

```
 minor_breaks=date_breaks("2 weeks")
```

in the scale_x_date line (along with several other variations), but the minor_breaks doesn't seem to be working for me. I've also tried variations of

```
 myminor=seq(from=1,to=365,by=15)
```

and using that for minor_breaks, but that didn't work either. Finally, I tried

```
g<-g+theme(axis.ticks.x=element_line(myminor))
```

but that also proved ineffective. I feel like it's a simple fix but I'm stuck.

Comment: Have a look at the examples here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_datetime.html

Comment: I looked at those previously before posting here, but thanks! My problem is that I want to keep the way my x-axis is labeled currently with the date_breaks (i.e., above - Jan-14, Feb-14, etc.), but just change the ticks.

Comment: Ya, that is going to take some work. let me think of a hack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly hacky, but somewhat closer to what you seem to want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
y=(1:12)
x=seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="months")
df=data.frame(x,y)
g<-ggplot(df,aes(x,y))
g<-g+geom_line()

labels <- date_format("%b")(x)
breaks <- as.Date(sort(c(as.POSIXct(x), 
                         as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date("2014-01-15"), 
                                        as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="months")),
                         ymd("2015-1-1"))))
labels <- c("", 
            as.vector(rbind(labels, 
                            rep("", length(labels)))))

g + scale_x_date(labels = labels, breaks = breaks, limits=range(breaks)) + 
    theme(axis.ticks.x=element_line(colour=c("black", 
                                             rep(c(NA, "black"), t=12))),
          panel.grid.major.x=element_line(colour=c("white", 
                                                   rep(c(NA, "white"), t=12))),
          panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank())
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Hacky or not, you're a magician! I was able to duplicate the example you posted and after a little tweaking was able to replicate it with my own data - look at that [good looking x-axis](http://i.imgur.com/5ZaNmA4.png)! I'm so new that I don't have enough reputation to vote up your solution but it worked - thanks a bunch!

Comment: this is indeed very hacky. is there a better solution by now?